# Eclipse 2019-03 regarding Java modules and maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit5, java-module

I am having a maven (3.6.0) project based on java 11 with the following structure (which works fine on the commandline!):

```
src/main/java/
  module-info.java
  /de/test/tp/TP.java

src/test/java/
  /de/test/tp/test/TPTests.java
```

The module-info.java looks as following:

```
module de.test.tp
 {
  exports de.test.tp;

  requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
 }
```

TP.java:

```
package de.test.tp;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class TP
 {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(TP.class);

  public TP()
   {
    super();
    LOGGER.info("test");
   }
 }
```

TPTests.java:

```
package de.test.tp.test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import de.test.tp.TP;

public class TPTests
 {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(TP.class);

  public TPTests()
   {
    super();
   }

  @Test
  public void defaultConstructor()
   {
    final TP tp = new TP();
    assertNotNull(tp, "Default constructor failed!");
   }
 }
```

Last but not least the important parts of pom.xml

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
          <optimize>false</optimize>
          <debug>true</debug>
          <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
          </dependency>

        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

   </dependencies>
```

When I now say (from within Eclipse) "maven/update project" the eclipse puts all maven dependencies to the **classpath**. After recompiling eclipse tells me:

```
The package org.apache.logging.log4j is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, org.apache.logging.log4j
```

for both `org.apache.logging.log4j` imports.

So the question is, how to fix that?

**Update 1**

What I really want is a clear project structure for a java modules project that is based on maven, works in eclipse and supports white- and blackbox testing. Can somebody give me such a project skeleton?

**Update 2**

Or is my problem that eclipse does not have multi-module support as I read in some articles? - Which also would lead me back to the question of Update 1.

**Update 3**

Shortened the whole question and added complete (shortened) file contents.

**Note 1**

During all my testing for example with having a seconds module-info.java under `test/java/` I found that eclipse 2019-03 is very instable and has bugs! For example - Sometime when trying to delete the module-info.java under test - Eclipse was not able to delete it. Another effect was that when editing the module-info.java with the test path eclipse also edit's the module-info.java under the main path. This means that within the main module-info.java I found that the exort has changed to de.test.tp.test - when I fixed that (in eclipse editor) I could not save the file. When I fixed that in an external editor and refresh/clean the project eclipse still tells me that the de.test.tp.test would not exist - so I have to delete the errors manually from the marker tab.

So from my point of view eclipse 2019-03 has some bugs regarding the handling of java modules.

**Note 2**

As you can see from the comments below @howIger has reported this as a [bug in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546315).

**Note 3**

Looks to me like it is fixed now in eclipse 2019-06 :)

Comment: To your first question: the problem is that the same package name is used in two modules (the _unnamed_ module contains everything on the classpath) because the Java language specification says so. To your final question: `modules-info.test` is neither Java nor Maven and therefore ignored by Eclipse. I would recommend to stick to the standard and do it without a `modules-info.test`.

Comment: Thats strange I have often read modules-info.(java|test) - maybe thats from prerelease? So I have now removed the modules-info.test which still leads to the above errors. Then I have renamed the test package to be the same as the implementation - still the same error - when I add a modules-info.java to the test package - for adding modules dependencies - then eclipse claims it als doubled. So still eclipse drives me crazy ...

Comment: As I now understand the modules-info.test is for commandline options that are supported by some ide's - and I put the wrong content into it.

Comment: Added Update 1 at the end of the question.

Comment: Added Update 2 at the end of the question.

Comment: The `modules-info.test` is not Java. Probably you are using a special Maven plug-in that does prepocessing based on this file (creating a `module-info.java` that is used instead of the regular `module-info.java` for testing only). The _package ... accessible from more than one module_ issue is a restriction by Java, not by the IDE you used (with _"Eclipse drives me crazy"_ you are shooting the messenger). In your case, the package `org.apache.logging.log4j` exists in the module with the same name and in the _unnamed_ module which is a JAR on the classpath.

Comment: I have changed the headline, also please forget about the module-info.test. But still my small example works only on the commandline with maven but not within eclipse - I really have read a lot (2 books and more web articles) about java modularisation - but for me eclipse works not as expected (by me - and I am using eclipse since the beginning) - so java modularisation with eclipse is really frustrating for me - maybe because I am not getting the point. But all other people I know are still on Java 8 - which also not really helps ....

Comment: To fix the problem, you need to correct the _Java Build Path_. For Maven, this means that your dependencies in the `pom.xml` do only work with the Maven plug-in that does prepocessing based on `modules-info.test`. Probably you would only have to get rid of the JAR with the `org.apache.logging.log4j` package on the classpath (by removing it or moving it to the modulepath), which you probably use for testing. But to answer your question one would need to know the `pom.xml` file and why you need the package in the main and test code.

Comment: As said above - please forget about the modules-info.test - that was a mistake/missunderstanding of mine and has been removed. - There is no special magic within the maven pom - only the normal compile plugin.
Maybe my question must be: how to put dependencies on the class or modulepath in maven pom?

Comment: In the Maven POM adding `<scope>test</scope>` moves a dependency from the modulepath to the classpath and makes it accessible in the test code only. To use dependencies on the modulepath (without `<scope>test</scope>`) in the `module-info.java` a `requires ...` is required.

Comment: Thats clear to me - but brings me only back to the original question - when I use "maven/update project" in eclipse - why every dependency is then in the classpath and not only the test dependencies? - I think my problem(s) are in details - not in general.

Comment: I doubt that's the case. Please give an example (`pom.xml` and Java code) to reproduce that.

Comment: I have to correct myself: the `requires org.apache.logging.log4j;` statement pulls the log4j dependency from the classpath to the modulepath (not the Maven scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that there is **more than one module** (probably a JAR) that **contains the package `org.apache.logging.log4j`** (or to be more precise, from which the package is accessible). This is **not allowed in the Java Platform Module System** (JPMS). But in this case, there is only one JAR that contains the package, so this **error is shown by mistake in Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11)**. See:

[**Eclipse bug 546315** - "The package […] is accessible from more than one module: , […]" error shown in Java editor by mistake](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546315)

**As workaround** for this bug do one of the following:

- **In `module-info.java` add the line `requires org.apache.logging.log4j.core;`** which pulls all related JARs on the modulepath
- Ignore the error (as it does not prevent the code to be compiled)
- Downgrade to Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) or wait until Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12)

By default, all Maven dependencies are on the classpath. In `module-info.java` the line `requires org.apache.logging.log4j;` pulls the JAR with the `org.apache.logging.log4j` module on the modulepath. The error erroneously states that there is another JAR on the classpath (and therefore in the *unnamed* module) that also contains the package `org.apache.logging.log4j`. Please note, `modules-info.test` (with the file extension `.test`) is neither a Java nor a Maven thing and therefore for Eclipse only a text file.

**Multi-module support**: in your case you have only one `module-info.java` which means you only have one Java module. In Eclipse **for each Java module a Java project is required** (due each module has its own dependencies).

Comment: Sorry for the late resonse, but I have rewritten the whole question (after testing a lot more), added more source and added a note about the bugs I found in eclipse 2019-03).

Comment: @PowerStat You cannot put a second `module-info.java` file into `src/test/java` because both Java files would be compiled into the same class file `target/classes/module-info.class`. But even having two output folders, it wouldn't make sense to put the test code into a separate module, since you usually want to access non-exported, non-public main code as well. For me Eclipse works like a charm with Maven and JPMS, but I prefer OSGi over JPMS for modularisation because of all the limitation of JPMS.

Comment: @PowerStat If you find real bugs (not just issues due to JPMS restrictions) please report them to Eclipse with an example of how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @howIger In the new example I don't have another module - but your position is whitebox testing only - for real blackbox testing I naturally need a second module, otherwise its not a real blackbox test - and surely I would like also to have my blackbox tests within the same project and thats a point eclipse fails, because of the in stone chiseled osgi history of eclipse .... but thats a point of phylosophy vs supporting a complete standard (that might also not be very well written ;-)

Comment: @PowerStat How the structure looks best with tests and modules (which by the way is not covered by the Java language specification) was discussed a decade ago and not just since JPMS. If you want to have multiple Java modules in one project, where do you want to display dependencies? What does it mean when one project references another? If you want to group modules, why not nested projects? Modules are about encapsulation and projects are about encapsulation. Therefore, it makes sense to use the same encapsulation (one project per module) instead of adding unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @howIger That dependes on the size of the project - for larger projects I agree with you - for smaller I see it as an overhead. But let's please go back to the example I gave - I am still having this "The package org.apache.logging.log4j is accessible from more than one module" while only having one(!) module-info.java. So what is wrong with this concrete example from above?

Comment: @PowerStat You have more than one module (probably more than one JAR) that contains the package `org.apache.logging.log4j` which is not allowed by the Java language specification when using JPMS (= having a `module-info.java`). Different packages may contain classes with the same name, but different modules must not contain packages with the same name when using JPMS.

Comment: @howIger Ok I think now I got it - we are talking about the split package problem - right? So I only have the dependencies listed above - so could only be: log4j-api and log4j.log4j-core. Which make it an interesting point: log4j-api contains the package (inculding classes within it and with subpackages) - log4j-core contains the org.apache.logging.log4j.core package (and no classes within org.apache.logging.log4j) ... in my understanding of split packages this is legal - maybe a bug in eclipse? Within Junit and within my own code there is no log4j package!

Comment: @PowerStat Show me the example that proves your claim.

Comment: @howIger The exmaple is above - give me some time to create it as github project and to make sure that it is not a problem of one of the plugins I have installed - I will let you know when I have it available (may take one or two days).

Comment: @howIger Ok I verified it now with a fresh clean eclipse 2019-03jee with the ame result. You can find the mini example project at http://www.powerstat.de/test.zip

Comment: @PowerStat I have reported this as [Eclipse bug 546315](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546315). As workaround ignore the error (as it does not prevent the code to be compiled and as it is only shown in the Java editor), put all affected JARs on the modulepath (in `module-info.java` via `requires ...`) or downgrade to Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10).

Comment: @howIger Thanks for reporting this bug 8-)

Comment: @howIger How about adding the link to the bug report to your answer, so that I could accept it?