# Build error related with the build path using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the below error message in eclipse. Most fixes I have seen say
add the jar to the classpath instead of the modulepath, but mine is in
the classpath and I still have the error:

```
Eclipse build path: The package org.apache.commons.lang3 is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, org.apache.commons.lang3
```

Comment: You get this error because you have a `module-info.java` file with a line like `requires org.apache.commons.lang3;` but in addition also a JAR which also contains the `org.apache.commons.lang3` package (at least two JARs that contains that package). See for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55592503/6505250 Deleting the `module-info.java` file or get rid of the second JAR containing the package should fix this issue.

Comment: Interesting. I actually didn't have a module-info.java, however I made one and that fixed the issue. I'm a little unclear on what modules, classpath and modulepath actually are so an explanation of why this worked would be helpful

Comment: If it is not Maven project, but a plain Java project in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_ libraries can be manually put on the _Modulepath_ or on the _Classpath_. Also, your code might contain the package. In your case the package `org.apache.commons.lang3` is accessible via both, via the _Modulepath_ and via the _Classpath_ which Java does not allow. Since your question doesn't contain any information about your project, you have to find out for yourself where exactly.