# gfe.jar SDLParser from java 1.6 to java 11

Tags: java, xml, sax, java-9

Hy,
I've ported an old 1.6 java desktop application to java 11, a lot of problems concerning jaxb no more supported on jre but at the end the application is running. Actually I've a problem with a jar named gfe.jar especially on class

```
 de.vcs.spc.ett.sdl.SDLParser extends org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler
```

in the jar aren't available source files. Do somebody know if it is available a more recent version of this jar that actually is compiled with java 1.6 instead i need it for java 11.

the exception is:

```
 "de.vcs.spc.ett.sdl.UnknownTypeException: Unknown type 'IdentifiedBlock'."
```

coming from:

```
    final FieldDef fieldDef = 
        SDL_PARSER.createFieldDef("IdentifiedBlock");
```

The same code with the same libraries is working well on Linux.

On internet I can't find any information about this.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226222/xml-api-jar-and-org-xml-sax-classes-having-issues-with-java-11

Comment: And if possible, it would be better if you could use the Java 17 :)